Show made in the 2010s-2012s where the main premise is kids controlling monsters with swords who drive race cars
I used to watch this show and I really wanted to find if it used to be on Netflix or still is, but I can not remember the name

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you saying it was on Netflix, or just that you were hoping to find it there?  And do the monsters drive the race cars or the kids?

Can you tell us anything more about the show? Like any specific events that happened? Or what any of the characters/monsters/cars looked like?

@DavidW: Are we certain that the swords don't drive the cars?

It could be (1) The kids controlled the monsters, who have swords and drive race cars, (2) The kids controlled the monsters with swords, and the monsters drove race cars, (3) The kids controlled the monsters with swords, and also drove race cars, (4) The monsters had swords, and were controlled by kids who drove race cars, (5) The kids control the monsters and the swords drive the race cars, (6) The kids have dual-function swords that drive race cars and allow them to control monsters, (7) I'm running out of characters, so I'll leave this open.

Is it Monkart: Legend of Monster Kart? It came out in 2017, which is after you said you watched it, but it fits the description perfectly.

Carmon Kingdom is a medieval style fantasy world where humans and
monsters live together. Monkart Race is the most popular sport in the
kingdom, as the highest ranker can be selected as knight. 12 year-old
Jin of Latona Village also dreams to be the winner someday. One day,
Destro, commander of the knights, invades the kingdom and tries to
marry princess Sena. The princess escapes and comes across Jin. Their
encounter awakes a dragon monster named Draka, who has been sealed in
Jin's sword.
Now Jin, Sena, and their monsters start the most exciting adventures
to save the kingdom.





Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It's a bit later than the time frame, and I haven't found the swords yet, but might it be Power Battle Watch Car (2015)?


The series is set in "the not so near future". An automobile company named JHC Motors has created WatchCars, which are miniature sentient robotic cars that have become good companions to children and adults alike. Ever since, Watch Cars have become a global trend. The WatchCar Battle League is a competition where WatchCars battle alongside their trainers. Jino, one of the young Watch Car Masters, goes to the Watch Car Battle League with his Watch Car Bluewill. As the undefeated and undisputed champion of the league, Kai, Jino's opponent, remains a legend. Jino and his WatchCar Bluewill dodge various obstacles ahead to defeat him and become the new league champion. Meanwhile, the evil organization the Black Shadows attempts to eliminate all WatchCars using their "Monster WatchCars".

The show was apparently sponsored by Hyundai.
Opening Song



Found with a search for netflix cartoon kids controlling monsters swords cars
